# Seeking list-detail Reactjs component library

Tags: web-apps, web-development, mobile, react, responsive-design

I'm building a Reactjs app. I would like to find a React component library or open source project that implements the familiar MasterList-Detail UX pattern so familiar with modern mobile apps. Similar to the demo contained in the below GIF.

I need a UX component that let's me implement a list, then after clicking on the list, show the detail of that list item.

Something like:

```
<ListDetail list={foo} />
```

Figure 1. List-Detail Demo. Shows the familiar list view, then detail reveal after clicking a list item.

[image: Figure 1]

Another example.

Figure 2. Same basic pattern as Fig. 1. I am seeking a React component library or open source project.

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 1):

[Essential ListView EJ 2 for React](https://www.syncfusion.com/react-ui-components/listview) supports creating these kind of lists.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-contact?file=index.js)

[image: Essential ListView based sample]

[image: Essential ListView based sample]

- The list-item and inner level navigation items are customized using ListView template property.
- Search has been achieved using Syncfusion DataManager query
- Included comments for each methods of StackBlitz sample

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.